# LinearSolve in Mathematica, used to find square matrix

Tags: matrix

Another issue I have with Mathematica today is that I want to solve the following matrix equation:

```
X.b=c
```

where b and c are two vectors, and X is a square matrix. How can I use LinearSolve to find X ? Or another function?

Comment: Of course I read the documentation. LinearSolve[m,b] solves an equation of the form m.X=b , where X is your unknown matrix. The above equation has the left hand side switched, it's the only way a square matrix can be multiplied with a vector. Thus, I need to somehow modify LinearSolve.

Comment: the m in the docs is not the unknown.  http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LinearSolve.html

Comment: You're right, I didn't read carefully.  But the problem you state doesn't make a lot of sense.  For an $n\times n$ matrix you only have $n$ equations but $n^2$ unknowns.  So there are infinitely many solutions.  There's always a trivial solution in the form of a diagonal matrix.  The diagonal entries will just be `c/b`.

Answer (score 6):

Take the 2 by 2 case: `{{a11,a12},{a21,a22}}.{x1,x2}={b1,b2}`. If `x` and `b` are known and `a` is unknown, you can reformulate the problem to look like this: `{{x1,x2,0,0},{0,0,x1,x2}}.{a11,a12,a21,a22}={b1,b2}`. Now it is in the form where you can apply  `Solve` or `LinearSolve` to find the `a`. Of course the answer will not be unique. In this case an answer is

```
x = {{x1, x2, 0, 0}, {0, 0, x1, x2}};
a = {a11, a12, a21, a22};
b = {b1, b2}
LinearSolve[x, b]
```

{b1/x1, 0, b2/x1, 0}

or more generally:

```
Solve[x.a == b, a]
```

{{a12 -> b1/x2 - (a11 x1)/x2, a22 -> b2/x2 - (a21 x1)/x2}}

`Solve` gives a warning, letting you know that this answer is not unique.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, works great.